# Unable to use `unittest.create_autospec` for a specific class method

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have tried to use `create_autospec` in order to recreate a method's signature. I discovered that the function did not work as I intended. It is sufficient for me for the `create_autospec` function to raise an exception if for some reason it cannot create a spec, rather than silently fail to constrain the function fully. My current workaround was to modify the source code in the `unittest.mock` module but this solution does not satisfy me. Is there a proper, 'pythonic' way to make `create_autospec` fail when no signature can be obtained? I would like to avoid wrapping the module as well. I am using Python 3.5.2.

```
from inspect import signature
from unittest.mock import create_autospec, Mock
import sqlite3

class Class(object):
    def method(self):
        return 'Class_method'

def function():
    return 'function'

method_mock = create_autospec(Class.method, return_value='mock_Class_method')
function_mock = create_autospec(function, return_value='mock_function')
cursor = sqlite3.connect(':memory:').execute('Select 1')
fetchall_mock = create_autospec(cursor.fetchall, return_value='mock_cursor')

print(method_mock('self'))
print(function_mock())
print(fetchall_mock())
print(fetchall_mock(1))
print(cursor.fetchall())
print(cursor.fetchall())

try:
    method_mock()
except TypeError:
    print('autospec working for method_mock!')

try:
    function_mock(1234)
except TypeError:
    print('autospec working for function_mock!')

try:
    print(cursor.fetchall(1))
except TypeError as e:
    print('autospec NOT working for fetchall_mock: {0}'.format(e))

try:
    signature(cursor.fetchall)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

> ```
> mock_Class_method
> mock_function
> mock_cursor
> mock_cursor
> [(1,)]
> []
> autospec working for method_mock!
> autospec working for function_mock!
> autospec NOT working for fetchall_mock: fetchall() takes no arguments (1 given)
> no signature found for builtin <built-in method fetchall of sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2e8b885ea0>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = sqlite3.connect(':memory:').execute('Select 1')
fetchall_mock = create_autospec(cursor.fetchall, ...)  # This line doesn't effect cursor.
```

You need to patch it in.

```
with mock.patch.object(cursor, 'fetchall', autospec=True, ...) as fetchall_mock:
   try:
       print(cursor.fetchall(1))
   except TypeError as e:
       print('autospec NOT working for fetchall_mock: {0}'.format(e))
```